# Help me name my class

Tags: oop, class, naming

Okay, first, here's my rather poor diagram...
[image]

It's worth noting the "Name Me" class may be listening to more than one `RequestNotifier`

It's safe to assume all Work Items that are put on the Work Queue are taken off the work queue by something else not shown and are processed exactly the same.

The only difference between the work items is the name (or id, but the name is my id in this) of the WorkItem that's being requested.

`Name Me` listens to Requests to work on a specific WorkItem, it then asks (a repository or some other data access class) for a WorkItem with that name, if one exists, submits it to the Work Queue. If none is found it ignores it and it's safe to do so.

Any ideas for a name, or if not a name, a better design that would make naming easier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NotificationBroker` gets my vote.

The primary responsibility of that class seems to be listening to notifiers and Brokering those Notifications to multiple Worker Queues.

Comment: I like this one. I shamefully admit I had to look up the definition of Broker. But it does fit quite well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

KISS Principle

```
class Listener
```

Answer (score 2):

RequestListener

WorkRequester

WorkManager

Comment: I like WorkManager or WorkRequester.

Answer (score 0):

WorkItemSubmitter

Most of the suggestions done so far make sense to me.